# Scss Selector for an element with 2 classnames

Tags: css, sass

I am looking for a css selector for adjacent classnames.

Ie:

```
<div className="container, greeting">Hi</div>
```

So that is a div with 2 classNames. I need a scss selector that will only apply styles for an element with those 2 classnames attached to it. I have tried:

```
.container {
  & + .greeting {color: blue}
}
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Class names should be separated by spaces alone, no commas, in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` selects the immediately next sibling.

You want to select an element that has both classes rather than select the next one so this should work better:

```
.container {
  &.greeting {color: blue}
}
```

And as others have pointed out, look at the formatting in className (class attribute).

Comment: how to prevent the smart naming in scss modules for eg. the .greeting class/selector?
edit: solved with eg. &:global(.Mui-checked)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid, you don't need a comma in the class property, you just put a space between them. I think this is why your SCSS isn't working

```html
<div className="container greeting">Hi</div>
```

Otherwise, in vanilla CSS this is possible, it's just this:

```css
.container.greeting{
   styles
}
```

Comment: If it's useful to still use SCSS nesting, for example if you have rules that only apply to `.container` and you want to keep them in the same place, then you can have the nested SCSS selector `&.greeting` to create that CSS rule.

Comment: @MarkHanna As far as I'm concerned it's just slight notation simplification, saves a few lines.

Comment: I need to use scss

Comment: @CryptoGeek981 This works regardless, the issue was with the way you wrote your classnames. in the HTML, not the CSS.

Comment: I wrote the example theoretically of what it would look like. That was not how it was written in the app. The main thing I needed was a selector that applies to an element with both classnames